# How to resolve NuGet "The package integrity check failed" errors?

Tags: nuget, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

My development environment is as follows:

- Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2022 Professional
- .NET 6.0

I am new to using NuGet.  I am having *constant* problems with NuGet not being able to install packages with the error "The package integrity check failed."

These steps will reproduce the error consistently on my system:

1. Start VS, choose "Create a new project"
2. Filter for C# / Windows / Console and choose Console App (not the .NET Framework one)
3. Framework: .NET 6 (Long-term support)
4. Once VS finishes creating the project, right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select "Manage NuGet Packages..."
5. Click Browse, enter "microsoft.data.sqlclient" in the search box, then choose the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient item.  As of today the latest stable version is 4.1.0.  Click Install.  My package source is "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" if that is important
6. A lot of NuGet messages show up in the Output window, always ending with a NU3008 error.  Apologies for the verbosity, I am not sure how much of this is relevant:

```
Restoring packages for d:\dev\CoreConsoleTest\CoreConsoleTest.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.data.sqlclient/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.data.sqlclient/index.json 122ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.data.sqlclient/4.1.0/microsoft.data.sqlclient.4.1.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.data.sqlclient/4.1.0/microsoft.data.sqlclient.4.1.0.nupkg 742ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/azure.core/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identity.client.extensions.msal/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.memory/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.json/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identity.client/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.win32.registry/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.buffers/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.configuration.configurationmanager/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.caching/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encoding.codepages/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encodings.web/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.cng/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.principal.windows/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/azure.core/index.json 46ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/azure.core/1.6.0/azure.core.1.6.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identity.client.extensions.msal/index.json 123ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.json/index.json 133ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identity.client.extensions.msal/2.16.5/microsoft.identity.client.extensions.msal.2.16.5.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.json/4.6.0/system.text.json.4.6.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.memory/index.json 173ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.memory/4.5.3/system.memory.4.5.3.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identity.client/index.json 190ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identity.client/4.22.0/microsoft.identity.client.4.22.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.win32.registry/index.json 208ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.win32.registry/5.0.0/microsoft.win32.registry.5.0.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens/index.json 226ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens/6.8.0/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens.6.8.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.buffers/index.json 246ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.buffers/4.5.1/system.buffers.4.5.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/index.json 271ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/5.0.0/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource.5.0.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encoding.codepages/index.json 294ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.configuration.configurationmanager/index.json 310ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encoding.codepages/5.0.0/system.text.encoding.codepages.5.0.0.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.configuration.configurationmanager/5.0.0/system.configuration.configurationmanager.5.0.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.cng/index.json 319ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.caching/index.json 327ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.cng/5.0.0/system.security.cryptography.cng.5.0.0.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.caching/5.0.0/system.runtime.caching.5.0.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encodings.web/index.json 357ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encodings.web/4.7.2/system.text.encodings.web.4.7.2.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.principal.windows/index.json 381ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.principal.windows/5.0.0/system.security.principal.windows.5.0.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.memory/4.5.3/system.memory.4.5.3.nupkg 282ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identity.client/4.22.0/microsoft.identity.client.4.22.0.nupkg 392ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/azure.core/1.6.0/azure.core.1.6.0.nupkg 790ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identity.client.extensions.msal/2.16.5/microsoft.identity.client.extensions.msal.2.16.5.nupkg 721ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.json/4.6.0/system.text.json.4.6.0.nupkg 713ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens/6.8.0/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens.6.8.0.nupkg 621ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.buffers/4.5.1/system.buffers.4.5.1.nupkg 601ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/5.0.0/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource.5.0.0.nupkg 713ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.configuration.configurationmanager/5.0.0/system.configuration.configurationmanager.5.0.0.nupkg 684ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.caching/5.0.0/system.runtime.caching.5.0.0.nupkg 888ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.win32.registry/5.0.0/microsoft.win32.registry.5.0.0.nupkg 3605ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encoding.codepages/5.0.0/system.text.encoding.codepages.5.0.0.nupkg 3521ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.cng/5.0.0/system.security.cryptography.cng.5.0.0.nupkg 4748ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.encodings.web/4.7.2/system.text.encodings.web.4.7.2.nupkg 5143ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.principal.windows/5.0.0/system.security.principal.windows.5.0.0.nupkg 5121ms
Installed Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens 6.8.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash +7JIww64PkMt7NWFxoe4Y/joeF7TAtA/fQ0b2GFGcagzB59sKkTt/sMZWR6aSZht5YC7SdHi3W6yM1yylRGJCQ==.
Installed Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal 2.16.5 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash VlGUZEpF8KP/GCfFI59sdE0WA0o9quqwM1YQY0dSp6jpGy5EOBkureaybLfpwCuYUUjQbLkN2p7neUIcQCfbzA==.
Installed Azure.Core 1.6.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash kI4m2NsODPOrxo0OoKjk6B3ADbdovhDQIEmI4039upjjZKRaewVLx/Uz4DfRa/NtnIRZQPUALe1yvdHWAoRt4w==.
Installed System.Memory 4.5.3 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash 3oDzvc/zzetpTKWMShs1AADwZjQ/36HnsufHRPcOjyRAAMLDlu2iD33MBI2opxnezcVUtXyqDXXjoFMOU9c7SA==.
Package 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
Package 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying the author primary signature with certificate: 

Package 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA1 hash: F404000FB11E61F446529981C7059A76C061631E
Package 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Issued by: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Package 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Timestamp: 10/20/2020 9:29:58 AM

Package 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying author primary signature's timestamp with timestamping service certificate: 
  Subject Name: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping Signer - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  SHA1 hash: A9A4121063D71D48E8529A4681DE803E3E7954B0
  SHA256 hash: C474CE76007D02394E0DA5E4DE7C14C680F9E282013CFEF653EF5DB71FDF61F8
  Issued by: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping CA, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  Valid from: 12/22/2017 7:00:00 PM to 3/22/2029 7:59:59 PM

Installed System.Text.Json 4.6.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash 4F8Xe+JIkVoDJ8hDAZ7HqLkjctN/6WItJIzQaifBwClC7wmoLSda/Sv2i6i1kycqDb3hWF4JCVbpAweyOKHEUA==.
Installed System.Runtime.Caching 5.0.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash 30D6MkO8WF9jVGWZIP0hmCN8l9BTY4LCsAzLIe4xFSXzs+AjDotR7DpSmj27pFskDURzUvqYYY0ikModgBTxWw==.
Installed System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.7.2 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash iTUgB/WtrZ1sWZs84F2hwyQhiRH6QNjQv2DkwrH+WP6RoFga2Q1m3f9/Q7FG8cck8AdHitQkmkXSY8qylcDmuA==.
Installed System.Buffers 4.5.1 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash Rw7ijyl1qqRS0YQD/WycNst8hUUMgrMH4FCn1nNm27M4VxchZ1js3fVjQaANHO5f3sN4isvP4a+Met9Y4YomAg==.
Installed System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 5.0.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash aM7cbfEfVNlEEOj3DsZP+2g9NRwbkyiAv2isQEzw7pnkDg9ekCU2m1cdJLM02Uq691OaCS91tooaxcEn8d0q5w==.
Installed System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 5.0.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash tCQTzPsGZh/A9LhhA6zrqCRV4hOHsK90/G7q3Khxmn6tnB1PuNU0cRaKANP2AWcF9bn0zsuOoZOSrHuJk6oNBA==.
Package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
Package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying the author primary signature with certificate: 

Package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA1 hash: F404000FB11E61F446529981C7059A76C061631E
Package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Issued by: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Timestamp: 10/22/2020 1:50:36 PM

Package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying author primary signature's timestamp with timestamping service certificate: 
  Subject Name: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping Signer - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  SHA1 hash: A9A4121063D71D48E8529A4681DE803E3E7954B0
  SHA256 hash: C474CE76007D02394E0DA5E4DE7C14C680F9E282013CFEF653EF5DB71FDF61F8
  Issued by: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping CA, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  Valid from: 12/22/2017 7:00:00 PM to 3/22/2029 7:59:59 PM

Installed Microsoft.Win32.Registry 5.0.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash dDoKi0PnDz31yAyETfRntsLArTlVAVzUzCIvvEDsDsucrl33Dl8pIJG06ePTJTI3tGpeyHS9Cq7Foc/s4EeKcg==.
Package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Signature Hash Algorithm: SHA256
Package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying the author primary signature with certificate: 

Package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   SHA1 hash: A6E18D21B507879FC7F9C392A5CE355936E3AD2C
Package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json':   Issued by: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Timestamp: 1/31/2022 5:36:44 PM

Package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': Verifying author primary signature's timestamp with timestamping service certificate: 
  Subject Name: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping Signer - G3, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  SHA1 hash: A9A4121063D71D48E8529A4681DE803E3E7954B0
  SHA256 hash: C474CE76007D02394E0DA5E4DE7C14C680F9E282013CFEF653EF5DB71FDF61F8
  Issued by: CN=Symantec SHA256 TimeStamping CA, OU=Symantec Trust Network, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US
  Valid from: 12/22/2017 7:00:00 PM to 3/22/2029 7:59:59 PM

Installed System.Security.Principal.Windows 5.0.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash t0MGLukB5WAVU9bO3MGzvlGnyJPgUlcwerXn1kzBRjwLKixT96XV0Uza41W49gVd8zEMFu9vQEFlv0IOrytICA==.
Installed System.Security.Cryptography.Cng 5.0.0 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with content hash jIMXsKn94T9JY7PvPq/tMfqa6GAaHpElRDpmG+SuL+D3+sTw2M8VhnibKnN8Tq+4JqbPJ/f+BwtLeDMEnzAvRg==.
NU3008: Package 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The package integrity check failed. The package has changed since it was signed. Try clearing the local http-cache and run nuget operation again.
NU3008: Package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The package integrity check failed. The package has changed since it was signed. Try clearing the local http-cache and run nuget operation again.
NU3008: Package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The package integrity check failed. The package has changed since it was signed. Try clearing the local http-cache and run nuget operation again.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:14.2400739
```

What I have tried:

- Rebooting
- Clearing my local cache (I have tried this many times, both from the command line with the nuget program and VS under Tools, Options, NuGet Package Manager, Clear All NuGet Cache(s))
- Installing dependencies individually from NuGet
- Repairing the Visual Studio 2022 installation

I have been trying to resolve this for almost 2 days now and I'm starting to see the red mist.  I don't understand why this is failing or how to fix it, and I'm beyond frustrated with Microsoft for making the formerly simple process of adding dependencies complicated and opaque.  Please, any help?

**Update**

To clarify, this does not happen for every package, but it does happen every time for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (and other Microsoft packages).

I am using the latest version of the nuget command line tool (6.2.1.2)

I have tried all the suggestions made by Jingmiao Xu-MSFT below other than uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio.  Suggestion #2, copying over the failing packages from another machine, did work but I do not accept that as a tenable permanent solution.  Am I supposed to pester a coworker whenever I need to install packages from Microsoft?

I came across [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11712) which is nearly identical to mine, including the package and the package version.  Unfortunately it contains no details about the resolution.  If there is an issue with our corporate network I will need to take specifics to them.  What sorts of network features might tamper with a NuGet package download?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the error message said “Try clearing the local http-cache and run nuget operation again.” and [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3008) suggests to run `nuget locals http-cache -clear` or `dotnet nuget locals http-cache --clear` command to cleare local http-caches.

If it doesn’t work you can try the following methods:

1. Close VS, delete nuget.config file from `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`,

   delete `.vs` hidden folder of the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of the project,

   and then restart VS to regenerate that file to check whether it works.
2. copy the nuget packages Microsoft.Data.SqlClient from another worked PC into `%userprofile%.nuget\packages`. And then reinstall your nuget package there to check if this work.
3. download the latest `nuget.exe v6.2.1` from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and then close VS and restart your project and run this command under CMD:

   `nuget restore`.
4. Finally, you can try to uninstall your vs and reinstall it. After installation, you can check if the problem exists.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I was already using that version of nuget, and have already tried clearing my cache and files exactly as you describe.  Your second suggestion did work but it's not a viable long-term solution unfortunately.  I need to find and resolve the root cause.

Comment: According to the issue you found, this problem may be caused by proxy. If you want to add proxy settings into Nuget.config file, you can refer to these links: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section ) and (http://skolima.blogspot.com/2012/07/nuget-proxy-settings.html ). You can find Nuget.config file in  “%AppData%\NuGet\ “.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  It turned out to be security on our firewall.